# How to resolve this routing problem when configure it correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

Team i have routeconfig, but when i click this button to collect that routing for my URL, its throwing an error and need some help. Below is my order of sequence to it, please tell me if i omit something.

```
// Routing
   // Route to Courses.

            routes.MapRoute(
                name:"Courses",
                url:"courses-registration/",
                defaults: new { controller="Home",  action="CoursesRegistration", id =UrlParameter.Optional} // Concerned more here clearly.

            );
  // Route to home-page.
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); // This route to Account and i am using it.

  //GET/Courses-List
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CoursesRegistration()
        {
            return View();
        }

             <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="fire" href="@Url.Action("courses-registration", "Home")">Create Courses</a>
                        <script type="text/javascript">    
                            $('#fire').on('click', function (e) {



                            });
                            </script>
                    </div>
```

Comment: both these routes will work under the normal routing configuration... I don't really see a need to create route for specific action like you did with CoursesRegistration. Why did you configure them separately if I may ask? also, please include the error on the question.

Comment: Which error is it throwing?

Comment: Error/Application

Comment: @Mosia this is for my web development, must i not? Reason being other routing i have from the application works fine. what could i be missing? Surely my button is calling both action-name and controller name.

Comment: is `courses-registration` an action name? because your action is `action="CoursesRegistration"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have configured your routes is really not a way I would recommend.

I would advise you to keep it default for now unless you really need this customized because it'll tirelessly work for your scenario:

1. Leave the default Controller Routing Configuration

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new{ controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

2. Use annotations to write routes for your `CoursesRegistration` like:

```
[Route("Home/CoursesRegistration")]
public IActionResult CoursesRegistration()
{
    return View();
}
```

These suggestions should work for your given scenario, because I didn't see the need for you to configure `CoursesRegistration` seperately, unless you have other reasons which you have not quoted on the question.

Comment: Thanks man, it works. lesson learnt and wont forget it now moving forward. "Happy coding"

Comment: Cool @T2020Jackson, Happy Coding